# What would a language created by anthropomorphic and humanoid dogs look like?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

I imagined a language created by anthropomorphic and humanoid dogs.

The following phonemes are:

1. The simple vowels are: /a/ as in French *adolescent* (which naturally means adolescent), /ɶ/ as in Swedish öra (which means ear), /ə/ as in English about, /e/ as in Spanish *estado* (which naturally means state), /o/ as in Spanish *ogro* (which naturally means ogre), /i/ as in English easy, /y/ as in French *univers* (which naturally means universe), /ɯ/ as in Japanese *kuki* (which means air), and /u/ as in French *ouvrier* (which means worker).
2. The diphthongs are the same as in Spanish.
3. The semivowels are the same as in Mandarin Chinese.
4. The nasals are the same as in French.
5. The plosives/stops are: /p/ as in Spanish *perro* (which means dog), /t/ as in French *tortue* (which means turtle), /d/ as in French *diptère* (which naturally means dipteran), /g/ as in French *gorille* (which naturally means gorilla), and /q/ as in Kavalan *qaqa* (which means elder brother).
6. The fricatives are: /ɸ/ as in Japanese *fugu*, /v/ as in English virus, /θ/ as in English thick, /ð/ as in English father, /x/ as in Spanish *jalapeño*, /ʁ/ as in French *restaurant* (which naturally means restaurant), and /h/ as in English hippie.
7. The approximants are: the standard English r phoneme as in rice, the alveolar trill as in Spanish *guerra* (which means war), /l/ as in French *loup* (which means wolf).

The standard canine language has no affricatives, neither suffricates, or even sibilants.   It has no pharyngeal/epiglottal consonants, neither retroflex ones.

If we are taking into account a mouth which looks like more a dog's one than a human's one, are the phonemes that were mentioned realistic?

Comment: Potential answers in https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45328/what-phonemes-would-a-snouted-animal-e-g-dog-or-cat-be-able-to-pronounce and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/86067/what-would-a-language-spoken-by-caninoids-sound-like/87032#87032

Comment: Do you own a dog? Listen to it and try to map the sounds a dog makes to some human sounds. I'd also think about phonemic tone.